# jQuery to post to php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session

I have an index.html file which I want to run some jQuery when it is loaded. Essentially, I want to check to see if a user is already logged in based on some session variables.

So index.html will contain some jQuery which uses `$(document).ready(function(){ });`

In this function I want to just fire autheticate.php which checks to see if $_SESSION['user'] is set, if it is then it will redirect to home page otherwise it will redirect to login page...

how can I post in jQuery without having a html form? I just want to post to a url...

EDIT:

Based on @jondavidjohn's answer I changed my web app so that it uses index.php to check sessions:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  //go to home page
  header('Location: ...home.html');
}else{
  //go to login page
  header('Location: ...login.html');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is surely possible doing this with javascript, **but it is not secure at all...**

You need to be checking at the server level for `$_SESSION['user']` before you even send the content to the browser...

My answer would be to do the checking / redirecting with PHP before anything gets sent to the browser, it will be less complicated and more secure...

The reason a javascript solution is insecure is that you are relying on a technology that resides and is controlled by the client to control access to protected areas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.post(url, params), where url is a string and params is a hash with your post data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.post("/authenticate.php",null,function(data){

    // do something based on response returned
   if($data){alert("authenticated");}
    else
      alert("not authenticated");
    });
```

in your php file

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{    
 echo true;
}
else
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to post data via AJAX to a page.  Doing it this way won't allow the PHP script to redirect the user, you'll have to java JavaScript redirect them.

```
$.post('/path/to/page.php', {userID: 5}, function(data){
    // Use window.location to redirect
});
```

Or, you can create a "fake" `<form>` element, and post that.

```
var $form = $('<form/>').attr({
   method: 'post',
   action: '/path/to/page.php'
});
var $input = $('<input/>').attr({
  name: 'userID',
  type: 'text'
}).val('5');
$input.appendTo($form);
$form.submit();
```

I suggest you take @jondavidjohn's advice, and have PHP redirect the user before the page is sent to the browser.  That's much more secure.

Answer (score -1):

Why bother with the AJAX request? Since you're building the page with PHP, just have PHP embed some variables in a JavaScript block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var is_logged_in = <?php echo $_SESSION['logged_in'] ? 'true' : 'false' ?>;
</script>
```

This'd save you an HTTP round-trip to retrieve data you already had available.

Comment: he says he is working with an html file. so he can't embed it.

Comment: I would not recommend this way, because javascript is highly exploitable and not good securitywise, if you dont know what you are doing.

Comment: @Vince: it's trivial to do `mv index.html index.php`.

Comment: @Marc Downvote isn't mine. I know it's trivial I just wanted to mention it :)